# Define linear independence of a set of vectors in a finite dimensional vector space V

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Maybe the wording in the problem is what's making me a little confused, but i would like someones opinion on the work that I've done

I believe the problem is asking me to find a set of vectors in a specific dimension ($r^2$ for example) and prove that they are linearly independent

I choose the two vectors $A = (1,2)$ and $B = (3,4)$.

$x(1,2) + y(2,3) = 0$

after I used row reduction I got the solutions $x = 0$, $y = 0$,

thus, since $x = y = 0$, the vectors are linearly independent.

Do you think this is what they are asking me to do?

Comment: Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.

Comment: Is your title the exact wording of the problem? I think you are being asked to simply state the definition, there isn't much of a problem there to solve.

Comment: Yes, the title has the exact words from my book (i double checked)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In general, a set $S$ in a vector space is linearly independent if for any distinct $x_1, x_2, \cdots x_n\in S$, and for any scalars $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots \lambda_n$,
$$\sum_k \lambda_k x_k = 0 \implies \lambda_k = 0, 1\le k \le n.$$

Comment: So do you think they are asking me to find a SPECIFIC set of vectors that are linearly independent, or are they asking me to generalize all vectors, (in the same way you did)?

Comment: You have shown that the two vectors they asked you about are linearly independent.  Note: a set of two vectors is linearly independent iff one is not a scalar multiple of the other.